# How do i know what version of ObjC language am i using?

Tags: objective-c, version

This is kind of a silly question, but really, how can i tell whether i am using ObjC version 2 or something else?

I can always assume "the latest", but i'd rather know :)

Is there a command line check i can run? Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running 10.5 or later, or any version of iOS, your computer is running Objective-C 2. If you are writing code which you want to work on systems before this, you can check for the `__OBJC2__` macro, which will be defined only for Objective-C 2 and later systems.

```
#ifdef __OBJC2__
// use objective-c 2
#elif defined(__OBJC__)
// use objective-c 1
#else
// no objective-c
#endif
```

Comment: How can i check that macro? Where can i find it please?

Comment: @mac Use the code I posted (you can skip the `#elif` line if you want to ignore Objective-C 1, or the `#else` line if you want to ignore no Objective-C). If the compiler is in Objective-C 2 mode, it will create that macro automatically.